# Spring r2dbc multiple insert statement execute one by one

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, r2dbc

I really don't understand what am i doing wrong because insert of 30000 rows takes about 20 minutes.
I also tried to insert 30000 with datagrip and it just takes like 1 second.
I am also thinking of composing a string sql of the data and executing it.

```
public Mono<Boolean> insertOrders(List<ClientOrder> orders) {
        if (orders.isEmpty()) {
            return Mono.just(true);
        } else {
            return databaseClient.inConnectionMany(connection -> {
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement(OrderQueries.INSERT_ORDERS);

                for (int i = 0; i < orders.size(); ) {
                    var order = orders.get(i);

                    statement.bind("$1", order.getUserId())
                            .bind("$2", order.getUserName())
                            .bind("$3", order.getCustomerEmail())
                            .bind("$4", order.getCustomerMobile())
                            .bind("$5", order.getAmount())
                            .bind("$6", order.getCreateDate())
                            .bind("$7", order.getStatusChangeDate());

                    if (++i < orders.size()) {
                        statement.add();
                    }
                }
                return Flux.from(statement.execute()).flatMap((result -> result.map(((row, rowMetadata) -> row.get("id", Long.class)))));
            }).doOnError((error) ->
                    System.out.println(error.getMessage())
            ).collectList().map((list) -> {
                return list.size() == orders.size();
            });
```

I would like to get some advice on doing multiple insert using spring boot r2dbc on postgres.

Comment: Which database are you using? How is your connection configured? Why not just a foreach loop instead of this thing. Looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/259 it seems that your approach with `statement.add()` won't work.

Comment: Postgres 16 Im using default configs. just injecting org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient. 
The sketchy loop is needed to skip add() after last item, or the binding will get an additional row of variables that dont have values.

Comment: Also to note i have solved this by concatenating the sql string like
adding a row of parameters to finnaly have a query like 
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO (...column names ) VALUES (...firstSet), (...seondSet), .... ;" and calling
this.databaseClient.sql(sqlQuery )
and that insert works in just two second

Answer (score 0):

I also used similar solution to insert multiple entities https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java#L90, it is just an example.

I have encountered similar performance issue before when migrating data from old database to new database.

But for your case, based on my previous experience,I think it is better to break the long list to smaller batches.

For example, 50 items in a batch, that when inserting counter reaches 50, commit the transaction and flush data into database, and then reset the counter to next iteration, till all data are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever has this issue I treated it the dumb way. I just concatenated all the data with StringBuilder and in the end I had one sql insert query. It has lots of overheads, but in my case as it is a person business project and the data is pulled from an external API and can always be pulled again it is a good solution.